# How to install the latest version of gedit?

Tags: software-installation, gedit, configure

I want to report a bug report for gedit. Before reporting I want to install the latest version.

I downloaded the source and configure fails like this:

```
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.44' but version of GLib is 2.40.2
Requested 'gio-2.0 >= 2.44' but version of GIO is 2.40.2
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'gtksourceview-3.0' found
No package 'libpeas-1.0' found
No package 'libpeas-gtk-1.0' found
No package 'gsettings-desktop-schemas' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GEDIT_CFLAGS
and GEDIT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
make: *** Keine Targets angegeben und keine »make«-Steuerdatei gefunden.  Schluss.
make: *** Keine Regel, um »install« zu erstellen.  Schluss.
```

My question: What is the most easy and painless way to install the latest version of gedit?

I run Ubuntu 14.04

```
===> apt-cache policy gedit
gedit:
  Installiert:           3.10.4-0ubuntu4
  Installationskandidat: 3.10.4-0ubuntu4
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 3.10.4-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Latest version of gedit: 3.18.0

Comment: Who said that you should compile the program itself?

Comment: what is output of `apt-cache policy gedit`

Comment: Can you add which gedit version you want exactly and which Ubuntu version you use? Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid has gedit `3.10.4-0ubuntu10` in its main repositories.

Comment: @A.B. Who told me to compile?  I read this page:  https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ReportingBugs "Make sure that you use an up-to-date version of gedit. ..." I downloaded the latest version (tar.xz) and read INSTALL.

Comment: @guettli That's for reporting bugs to GNOME directly. Instead, report to Ubuntu first (`ubuntu-bug gedit`), then the Ubuntu devs will check with GNOME.

Comment: You are trying to use Gedit 3.18 on Gnome 3.10 - I have found with this and other Gnome apps that if often they not been fixed for older versions, you may be able to get it work to a degree (if you install those needed dependencies), but it will either have limited functionality or crash straight away...

Comment: @muru I should report at ubuntu first? ok, would be nice to read this on this page:  https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ReportingBugs ... OK, I understand. This page is not under control of ubuntu ...

Comment: @guettli - it isn't a bug, 14.04 has libaries that are to old for Gedit 3.18 to work effectivly - however you may be able to get it to work in 15.10/16.04. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/678967/178596