# How do I upgrade Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 Unity and Ubuntu based distros?

Tags: 14.04, unity, upgrade, nautilus

I am currently running Ubuntu Unity 14.04.x and Zorin OS 9 (14.04.x based distro).  Both OSs are running Nautilus 3.10.1.  Recently, Nautilus 3.18.1 was released.  This new version is not in the Software Center for upgrading.  And, it appears that Nautilus is not being supported for updates/upgrades when new releases are made.  I have downloaded the latest version.  However, it is not in the usual "deb".  It appears that latest version is not released by specific distro nor supported by Canonical or Ubuntu.  So, how do I manually upgrading Nautilus?  And, will Nautilus updates/upgrades every be supported?

Comment: Questions on Ubuntu-based distros are to be asked in [unix.se].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Nautilus 3.18 isn't available for Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 14.04 is too old, or the required libraries are too old. You could try it for yourself to compile. But you will not succeed. To use Nautilus 3.18 you need at least Ubuntu 15.10 with some additionally PPAs or wait for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Well then .... I guess that answered my question.   Wow!  I thought that with Ubuntu 14.04.x "LTS", new releases would be relevant and updated/upgraded.  Oh well.

Comment: If you guess "that answered my question", than you should mark the answer via the little tick at the left side of my answer. =)

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not that familiar with this forum.

Comment: At the left hand side of my answer should be a gray ✔. If an answer is valid, click on the ✔.

Comment: Roger that!  I did click on it already.  Take care.  I'm outta here.

Comment: Not really. See the example image. http://imgur.com/iAq9rYY, The ✔ is still gray ;)

Comment: @user250630, you've got it exactly backwards. Long Term Support releases are able to be supported long-term because the developers are very careful to include only well-tested, stable, proven software. You get security and some bugfix updates for the software versions that ship with the LTS release, but not new versions. If you want to run cutting-edge versions of things you need the _opposite_ of an LTS release, e.g. perhaps a nightly build. But you should know that you're trading stability for new-and-shiny; prepare to experience more bugs on a nightly.